# transpose data in 13 columns to 2 columns

Tags: excel, vba, transpose

i need to transform my monthly data calculations to a template on regular basis. this involves transposing data in such a way that each Account number is repeated 12 times, then period numbers and amounts are listed infront. if it sounds confusing i have attached a snapshop of source and target format. that would make it clear. any help would be greately appreciated. many thanks[Source and target format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8a9yk.jpg)
Source data is in hundreds of rows, I guess a vba solution will be best suited. I have very basic vba skills.

Comment: you can google for "Excel unpivot" for examples on how to do it with Power Query. Otherwise you can try the older way http://superuser.com/questions/78439/is-it-possible-to-unpivot-or-reverse-pivot-in-excel

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO,

Try these formula,

```
A9  =INDEX($A$2:$A$4,QUOTIENT(ROW() - ROW($A$9),12)+1)
B9  =INDEX($B$1:$M$1,1,MOD(ROW() - ROW($A$9),12)+1)
C9  =INDEX($B$2:$M$4,QUOTIENT(ROW() - ROW($A$9),12)+1,MOD(ROW() - ROW($A$9),12)+1)
```

Drag the formulas down. The ranges are as in the screeshot

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thank you very much. with some slight edits these formulas are working perfectly on my full data set. I am happier to have this non vba solution. Apologies I should have uploaded a file to save you time. I am indebted for your effort on this, much appreciated.

Comment: If this solved your problem, please accept the answer